# Remove duplicates in a collection and put into array

Tags: excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet, vba

I have a collection of Applicants. The collection has Names, University, Age, Date, etc.

I would like to create an array that just holds the unique Names from the Applicants collection.

I wanted to somehow create a new dictionary that uses the Names as keys since keys can't be duplicates:

```
Dim z As Variant
Dim d As Object

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each z In Applicants
    d(z("Names")) = 1
Next
```

However I do not know if this would work because I am running into errors. I want to create an array afterwards that will hold the unique keys or the Names in this case.

Comment: Do you want to create an array of unique names or a dictionary of unique names? It's not clear in your question.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a dictionary to get the unique names, then transfer that dictionary to an array, is that correct?  Also, it would be helpful to indicate what errors you're getting and where in your code the debugger is indicating the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the key exists before adding or you will throw an error. Additionally, you have the non-unique `.Item` in a Scripting.Dictionary that can store single or delimited fields from the same record.

```
For Each z In Applicants
    if not d.exists(z("Names")) then
        d.Add Key:=z("Names"), Item:=z("University") & "|" & z("Age") & "|" & z("Date")
    end if
Next
```

I'm not sure about `z("Names")` but you have not provided enough information about `Applicants` to prove more than what your sample was using. The `.Item`. can be retrieved using the key and a `Split` function on the delimiter will create an array.